# Bundling and minifying MVC project for production in ABP

Tags: bundling-and-minification, aspnetboilerplate

I have an ABP - ASP Net Core 2 - MVC template. I am not quite sure about the steps required to take to bundle and minify the Javascript and Css files. I have already gone through some tutorials in that regard but each required something which does not exist in the template, such as gulp or `project.json` file. Do I need to add these to the solution myself or there is another way of bundling? I can see that there is a `bundleconfig.json` file but quite sure how to trigger to update the .min files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABP has an article ([section](https://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html#ArticleFilterTasks)) that touches on using the [Bundler & Minifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) VS extension:

> I used **Bundler & Minifier** VS extension (which is default way of minifying files in ASP.NET Core projects) to minify the script:
>
> [image]
>
> This adds the following lines into **bundleconfig.json** file in the .Web project:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/views/tasks/index.min.js",
>   "inputFiles": [
>     "wwwroot/js/views/tasks/index.js"
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> And creates a minified version of the script:
>
> [image]
>
> Whenever I change the index.js, index.min.js is automatically re-generated.